# Is there a way to generate a set of random UUIDs using one `random_uuid` resource in Terraform

Tags: azure, random, terraform, uuid, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to deploy few sentinel automation rules for a sentinel solution using Terraform. Because the automation rules require a UUID for its name, I'm using `random_uuid` resource per each automation rule to generate a UUID for the names of automation rules. The code looks like the following. I want to know is there a way to generate all the random UUID values for my automation rules through a single random_uuid resource or something like that.

```
resource "random_uuid" "automation_rule_1" {}

resource "azurerm_sentinel_automation_rule" "automation_rule_1" {
  name                       = random_uuid.automation_rule_1.result
  log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id
  display_name               = "Automation Rule 1"
  order                      = 1
  triggers_on                = "Incidents"
  triggers_when              = "Created"
  enabled                    = true
  action_playbook {
    logic_app_id = var.logic_app_id
    order        = 1
    tenant_id    = var.tenant_id
  }
}

resource "random_uuid" "automation_rule_2" {}


resource "azurerm_sentinel_automation_rule" "automation_rule_2" {
  name                       = random_uuid.automation_rule_2.result
  log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id
  display_name               = "Automation Rule 2"
  order                      = 1
  triggers_on                = "Incidents"
  triggers_when              = "Created"
  enabled                    = true
  condition_json = jsonencode(
    [
      {
        conditionProperties = {
          operator     = "Contains"
          propertyName = "IncidentRelatedAnalyticRuleIds"
          propertyValues = [ var.sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled_id ]
        }
        conditionType = "Property"
      }
    ]
  )
  action_incident {
    order                  = 1
    status                 = "Closed"
    classification         = "BenignPositive_SuspiciousButExpected"
    classification_comment = "Sample Comment Goes Here"
    owner_id               = var.automation_rule_owner_id
  }
}
```

I expect something like the following. Can someone explain is there a way to achieve this type of behaviour.

```
resource "random_uuid" "automation_rule_ids" {
  keepers = {
    "rule_1_id" = "dont know what to put here",
    "rule_2_id" = "dont know what to put here"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Each instance of `random_uuid` will generate only one UUID, but you can use multiple instances of that resource type to generate multiple UUIDs.

For example:

```
variable "rules" {
  type = set(string)
}

resource "random_uuid" "example" {
  for_each = var.rules
}

locals {
  rule_uuids = tomap({
    for rule_name, obj in random_uuid_example :
    rule_name => obj.result
  })
}
```

This defines `local.rule_uuids` as a map from rule names to UUID strings, using `for_each` with the `random_uuid.example` resource to declare multiple dynamic instances of that resource.

For example, if you set the `rules` variable to `["a", "b"]` then `local.rule_uuids` would have a value structured like this:

```
tomap({
  a = "aabbccdd-eeff-0011-2233-445566778899"
  b = "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff"
})
```

...though of course the actual UUID values will differ, due to them being random.

---

The above doesn't include any "keepers" because your question didn't define any rule for when the UUIDs would need to be regenerated. The use of `for_each` means that adding a new element to `var.rules` would cause Terraform to propose to generate a new UUID just for that rule key, and likewise removing an element from `var.rules` would make Terraform propose to discard one of the UUIDs.

If you do need some sort of "keeper" for each then an alternative would be to make the input variable be a map and use the values as the "keepers" for each object:

```
variable "rules" {
  type = map(string)
}

resource "random_uuid" "example" {
  for_each = var.rules

  keepers = {
    v = each.value
  }
}

# (locals block unchanged)
```

`each.value` in the `resource` block refers to the value of the current element of the map, so the caller of this module could cause an existing UUID to be regenerated by changing the value assigned to its element in the map without changing the map key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was very helpful for me to understand whats going on inside of it. Considering the context of my problem, I understood the following;
1) I would not be needing `keepers` property because I do not want recreation of the resource in my context, I always want to modify them.
2) It would be better to use separate instances of `random_uuid` as I need them not only for automation rules, but also there are few Azure Workbooks too. So using a map to create random_uuids will put everything together which might be confusing.

Your comments on this is also appreciated.